# Apex Test issues creating a quote - page error missing or inactive pricing type/pricebook

Tags: apex, failing-tests

I am trying to update some older test code to remove seeallData=true.
I am getting a page error testing a quote controller extension that creates a new quote.

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: No error message must be
>   displayed(ApexPages.Message["Quoting cannot proceed with missing or
>   inactive Pricing Type/Pricebook."]): Expected: true, Actual: false

Here are snippets of the code which mostly I inherited and am working to clean-up :-)

Opportunity was created in a setup method using the standard pricebook id.

```
quote = new Quote(Name='test quote', OpportunityId=opp.Id, pricebook2id=Test.getStandardPricebookId());
Test.startTest();
        Test.setCurrentPageReference(Page.NewQuote);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('oppId', opp.Id);      
        stdCont = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(quote);
        contExt = new NewQuoteQuoteContExt(stdCont);
Test.stopTest();    
        System.assertEquals(true, contExt.isValid, 'No error message must be displayed' +  Apexpages.getMessages());
```

Comment: (1) +1 for getting rid of seeAllData=true; would everyone at SFSE be so good.  (2) The error message might be a custom message that your code or Validation rule generates as 'Pricing Type' is not a SFDC concept AFAIK. Perhaps something else (custom setting, custom object row) needs mocking that seeAllData=false exposed (3) Eric has a worthwhile idea too

Comment: Thanks crop1645!  good suggestions -  I did check for Vrules - but will look closer.  what seems odd to me is that in general you can create quotes without a pricebook in cases where the parent opp does not yet have products so no pricebook.  Also the developer who built this test seems to have created a VF page just for the test which is not used elsewhere - this doesn't seem like a best-practice to me but I am not well versed with VF/Controllers more experienced with Apex trigger code and batch Apex...

Comment: @debraSF the vf thing is odd

Comment: Did you scan the source code and metadata  to look for the message string 'Pricing Type/Pricebook' ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Standard Pricebook inactive?

if so try adding this to the testSetup or beginning of your test method or where you set up the data:

```
PriceBook2 stdPb = New PriceBook2(id=test.getStandardPriceBookID(), isActive = true);
update stdPb;
```

Comment: thanks Eric.  I did double check the price book is active - added some debug statements to the test code.  But will try your suggestion to create a pricebook explicitly for the test as this seems like a better practice anyway - not to rely on any real Org data as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

After quite of bit of testing I was able to resolve the failing test issue with a simple change to the Test class API version - changing the API version from 27 to 35 resolved all test failures.

Comment: excellent -- I'm surprised the test class even compiled if it was at V27 since `Test.getStandardPricebookId()` didn't show up until V31